# How to install the `next` branch of react-admin?

Tags: npm, installation, branch, yarnpkg, react-admin

I'm trying to install the `next` branch of react-admin.

I've tried `yarn add react-admin#next`, but then I get `"react-admin": "2.0.3"` in my package.json and I'm missing features that are only in the next branch.

I've tried `yarn add react-admin@next`, but then I get `"react-admin": "2.0.0-beta3"` and still missing the `next` features.

In between I ran these commands to be sure I'm not getting any cached stuff: `rm yarn.lock`, `rm -rf node_modules`, `yarn cache clean`

I also tried `yarn add https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin#next`, but then I get:

> yarn add v1.7.0
>
> [1/5]   Validating package.json...
>
> [2/5]   Resolving packages...
>
> error Can't add "react-admin-lerna": invalid package version undefined.

I also tried `yarn add https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin@next`, but then I get:

> yarn add v1.7.0
>
> ...
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin@next/': The requested URL returned error: 400

How to install the `next` branch of react-admin?

*Bonus question*

Subsequently, how do I install a local package, say `ra-ui-materialui` in the `next` branch?

Answer (score 2):

You can't because this is a monorepo using yarn workspaces and it contains all our react-admin related packages.

Comment: The only option for us to allow this would be to publish our packages under the `latest` or `next` tag

Comment: I certainly wouldn't mind working with the `next` branch